# how to join 2 different list to 1 list

Tags: c#, arrays, list, linq

How to join 2 list with linq to new list

```
public class list1
{
    public string ID { get; set; }
}

public class list2
{
    public string ID { get; set; }
    public string Member { get; set; }
}

public class result { get; set; }
{
    public string ID { get; set; }
    public List<list2> list2s { get; set; }
}
```

#### Inputs

list1 = `{a}, {b}, {c}, {d}`

list2 = `{a,1}, {a,2}, {a,3}, {b,1}, {b,2}, {c,1}, {d,1}`

#### Output

result = `{a,{1,2,3}}, {b,{1,2}}, {c,{1}}, {d,{1}}`

Comment: Why do you need to join them? List 2 is a superset of list 1, so you can simply return list 2.  (Maybe your example needs improving to show the problem better).

Comment: FYI, `list` is a terrible name for something that is not a list.  Your class is called `list1` but it is not a `List`.  You also then say `list1 = ...`, but `list1` is a class, so it doesn't _equal_ anything and can't be assigned anything.   Are you implying you have a `List<list1>` somewhere called `list1`?

Comment: Your requirement is not complete. If `list1` also contains `{e}`, but there is no `e` in list2, do you want `e` in your result? "e without any numbers"? And what if list2 contains `{f, {3}}`, but there is no f in list1?

Comment: I'm sorry for not clear question, I just try to join list into another list with array in row

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use join same as this code:

```
var l1 = new List<list1>() 
{ 
    new list1() { ID = "a" },
    new list1() { ID = "b" }, 
    new list1() { ID = "c" },
    new list1() { ID = "d" } 
};


var l2 = new List<list2>() 
{ 
    new list2() { ID = "a" ,Member = "1" },
    new list2() { ID = "a", Member = "2" },
    new list2() { ID = "a", Member = "3" }, 
    new list2() { ID = "b", Member = "1" },
    new list2() { ID = "b", Member = "2" }, 
    new list2() { ID = "c", Member = "1" }, 
    new list2() { ID = "d", Member = "d" } 
    
};
```

```
var x = from l in l1 
        join ll in l2 on l.ID equals ll.ID 
        select new result 
        { 
            ID= ll.ID,
            list2s= l2.Where(d => d.ID == ll.ID).ToList() 
        };
```

but you can use another solution

Comment: I tried to group after join but it doesn't work 

var x = from l in l1
                     join ll in l2 on l.ITEMID equals ll.ITEMID
                     group l by l.ITEMID into g
                     select new  { ITEMID = g.ITEMID, testModel2s = l2.Where(d => d.ITEMID == ll.ITEMID).ToList() };

but group after x get new select list it's work 

x = x.GroupBy(a => a.ITEMID).Select(a => a.FirstOrDefault()).ToList();

Thank you so much